# Publishing contents of randomly-generated form to twitter (with Javascript?)

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm HTML and slightly JavaScript literate, but no more and I want to add a 'Tweet this' link to the following page: http://virtualchrisleonard.co.uk/bjg.html

When a user clicks on the 'create journal' button and they see something they like, I'd like them to be able to tweet that result.

The content of the form is generated by JavaScript (see source). Is there a simple way I can do this with JavaScript?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, there is:

create a `<div id="twitter"></diV>` where you want your twitter button to be. after your button code add the following:

```
var text = (get the text you want to tweet);
var button = '<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="' + text + '" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>';
$('#twitter').html(button);
```

note: this example uses jquery for setting the html inside the div with 'twitter' id. Hence the $('#twitter').

Comment: Thanks. Will look into jQuery for this. Never used it before so I will at least learn something. Cheers.

Comment: JQuery is easy to learn and essential for serious JS development. It will be useful in the future. Remember to accept answers to your questions to help those who also have them (green thing bellow each answer vote).

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="tweet()"/>Tweet this!</a>
```

In your JS

```
function tweet() {
    window.open("http://twitter.com/home?status=Look at this great website " + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)); 
};
```

Comment: Thanks Jim - this works, but doesn't pull the randomly-generated text out of the form. I think I need to compress a couple of these suggestions into one to get the Tweet to contain the string.